# Azure Data Studio executable is not installed on macOS?

Tags: azure-data-studio

I have been using Azure Data Studio for 15 months and did not realize there is a command line tool available. Or actually is there a command line tool (on macOS)? There is no `azuredatastudio` in my path or under the `Applications/Azure Data Studio`.

[The Azure Data Studio Command line (from MSFT Learn docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-data-studio/command-line)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asmking here. Is it how to launch ADS from the command line, or is there a command line tool for SQL Server (which would be unrelated to ADS).

Comment: @ThomA  Documentation from ADS says there is an executable that is a terminal application and so we can run sql commands from the terminal.  But that app is not showing up on my `macOS`.   Since there is confusion on this I will add the reference to the docs mentionoing the command line progrram `azuredatastudio`. Ok so I updated the question with the link.